# Getting a part of URL with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, get

I would like to get this information from url with jQuery:

```
login
```

from this url:

```
http://www.domain.com/index.html#login
```

So what i would like, is to get the information from #
and later use the information that i got from # to make an include.
I know how to include a file, but i don't know how to get the information from the url, and from "#"

I don't really want to use &site=login, because it's my last option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pure JS:

```
console.log(window.location.hash);
```

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location

Answer (score 4):

Why not use `window.location.hash` ?

Answer (score 0):

The `window.location` object has a `hash` property.

```
console.log(window.location.hash);
```

Break up the values, if there are multiple with:

```
window.location.hash.split('#');
```

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery

```
var loc = $(window)[0].location;
var thingYouWant = $(loc).prop('hash').substr(1);
```

Comment: @Kristjan: Whoa I was being sarcastic, use [karim79's](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9249432/465546) answer. My way is a [Rube Goldberg](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rube_Goldberg_machine) way. You don't need jQuery for this.